# Prove that a user exported data from Quickbooks

Tags: security, export, quickbooks

An employee leaving the company has exported our entire customer list and a record of all of the individual product sales to each customer from Quickbooks.

I know that we should have had access restrictions in place to prevent this from happening in the first place, but that can't be helped now.

I want to prove that this user exported this data. However, as far as I can tell, Quickbooks does not log export operations. Is there any way to extract export history from Quickbooks?

Comment: Does QuickBooks log report generation? Do you have access to the employee's PC? Can you check their history of Excel files? Granted the user probably cleaned up the history, but it's worth a shot to look. If the file is there it should have creation time and document owner in its properties. I don't know much about QuickBooks, just thought I'd throw out some ideas. Good luck!

Comment: The guy was pretty lazy. The report that he ran is in the "Recent Reports" section of Quickbooks. He did not have access to Quickbooks on his computer, so he went our shipping computer and generated the report there. He then put the report into his folder on our shared drive/file server. 

I don't feel like taking a screenshot of the "Recent Reports" screen provides enough evidence. No timestamps, no usernames, no export filename. I wanted to build a concrete case.

I don't know if Quickbooks logs report generation. I couldn't find info online, so I thought I'd ask here. Thanks!

Comment: Does this: http://quickbooks.intuit.com/blog/keep-calm-view-the-quickbooks-online-audit-log/ or this: http://forums.quickbooksusers.com/showthread.php?t=24037 help at all?

Comment: Thanks for you help, but I don't think those will do it.
The Audit Log is for Quickbooks online, I'm using Enterprise 14.
I have inspected the Audit Trail as well and everything seems to focus on transactions. It makes sense. Having to check if someone changed prices or edited an invoice is much more common that checking to see if someone exported a report.

I at this point, I don't think Quickbooks logs information that is not about a transactional change to the file.